# Active record query for ANY test rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Job, Category and JobCategory models in my rails application. I am using postgresql as the database. I have many-to-many relationship between my Job and Category models. On my Job show page along with the job currently being shown I want to display all the jobs which belongs to the same category that of currently being shown job.

I tried this:

```
<% JobCategory.where(category_id = ANY (@job.categories)).each do |job| %>
```

but I am getting an error. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JobCategory.where('category_id in (?)', @job.categorie_ids)`

Comment: hey how can i exclude tha job being displayed currently ?

Comment: because when we are doing 'category_id in (?), @job.category_ids' its also including the current job

Comment: This can be done within a query `JobCategory.where('category_id in (?) and job_id != ?', @job.categorie_ids, @job.id)`